# How to exit the while loop if the condition satisfies

Tags: javascript

If condition is true exit the while loop, but my while loop is exits after another loop attempted.

```
let moveNavigation = 0;
            let currentItemFocus;
                let jsonString;
                let hasMovedList= false;

            currentItemFocus = yield page.getFocusedNode();
                    while (!hasMovedList) {
                        yield page.keys().press(page.keys().RIGHT);
                        currentItemFocus = yield page.getFocusedNode();
                        console.log(logger.modify.background.yellow(` inside while loop item focus node is ${JSON.stringify(currentItemFocus)}`));

                        hasMovedList= Object.values(currentItemFocus).includes(NAVIGATION_TO_LIST);
                        console.log(logger.modify.background.yellow(` has moved watchlist button status is ${(hasMovedList)}`));


                        moveNavigation++;
                    }
```

Comment: What makes you think your loopcontinues one more time? It doesn't. The only things that happen after you set your flag are the `console.log` and `moveNavigation++`. (There's no need for that `if` right at the beginning, that's what the `while` above it does.)

Comment: Even i tried without `if` condition. Even though, it tries to attempt another time.

Comment: Again, what makes you think that? Because it definitely doesn't. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Re your edit: A screenshot is not a [mcve]. Please **read** the link above.

Comment: Moreover, the screenshot just demonstrates that my comment and answer are correct.

Answer (score 0):

That code will exit the loop once `hasMovedList` is truthy. The only things that will happen after you set it to a truthy value are the `console.log` and `moveNavigation++;` after the statement where `hasMovedList` is set. If you don't want that to happen, `break` right away:

```
while (true) {
    yield page.keys().press(page.keys().RIGHT);
    currentItemFocus = yield page.getFocusedNode();
    console.log(logger.modify.background.yellow(` inside while loop item focus node is ${JSON.stringify(currentItemFocus)}`));

    if (Object.values(currentItemFocus).includes(NAVIGATION_TO_LIST)) {
        break;
    }
    console.log(logger.modify.background.yellow(` has moved watchlist button status is ${(hasMovedList)}`));

    moveNavigation++;
}
```

Comment: Tried your way as well but it tries to attempt another loop and exits.

Comment: @SenthilK - **Again**: No, it doesn't. Please update your question with a [mcve] showing why you *think* that it does. It does not.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `if` statement at the begining of `while`. To exit loop you need to change `hasMovedList` to be `true`.

Comment: Yes, tried that as well. But it still not exits when condition is true.

Comment: It means the variable is still false